# Memory limit exceeded in AppsScript Google Sheets bound function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Have you ever met the cases when the owner of Google Sheets **doesn't have the "Exceeded memory limit" error** when running bound script, and the editor of the same document does?

I have a report in Google Sheets which is created as the result of API request to Google BigQuery. Here's my bound script (I excluded the full SQLquery text, because it's not the issue):

```
function Report_detailed() {
   var t = new Array(0);
  var projectId = 'project_id';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Detailed_report");
  var result = sheet; 
  var dateFrom =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Detailed_report").getRange("B1:B1").getValue()),"GMT+3", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var dateTo =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Detailed_report").getRange("B2:B2").getValue()),"GMT+3", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(6,1,lastRow,55).clearContent(); 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G6:BC");
  cell.setNumberFormat("0.00");
  var request = {
        query: 
'                SELECT * '+
'                FROM '+
'                `project_id.dataset_id.table_name` '+ 
'                WHERE '+    
'                date  BETWEEN "'+dateFrom+'" AND "'+dateTo+'" ',    
        useLegacySql: "FALSE",
  } ;
  t[0] = new Date();
  t[0] = 'Stage 1'+t[0];
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  t[1] = new Date();
  t[1] = 'Stage 2'+t[1];
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

    // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 1000;
  var n = 0;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    n = n + 1;
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
  t[2] = new Date();
  t[2] = 'Stage 3'+t[2];
  Logger.log ('jobs');

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken,
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }
  t[3] = new Date();
  t[3] = 'Stage 4'+t[3];
  if (rows) {

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    t[4] = new Date();
    t[4] = 'Stage 5'+t[4];
      Logger.log ('datas');

    sheet.getRange(6, 1, rows.length, 55).setValues(data);
    t[5] = new Date();
    t[5] = 'Stage 6'+t[5];    
    Logger.log(t.join('\\n'));

    Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s');
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
  return n;
}
```

**Additional info:**

1. The function is called from UI.
2. The query size is about 100 MB, so it's performed very fast.
3. The first 4 stages are run in 1-2 minutes
4. The result table has about 25 000 rows. So the longest part of the process is **setting values to the cells.**
5. The Sheets locale is the US, the owner is in Ukraine, the editors of the file are in the other country.

When I run the function from my Google Account, everyting's OK, and I get the result table in 5-6 minutes.

But when my colleagues from the other country try to refresh the report in their Google Accounts, applying the same date range as I do, they have "Memory limit exceeded" without any detailed explanations.

Could you please help me to find the roots of the issue?

I'd appreciate any clues and recommendations. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have a paid G Suite account and is your colleague using a free Gmail account?

Comment: You can wrap the entire function in a `try/catch` and when there is an error, get the stack.  That will tell you what line the error occurred on.  I'd use `console.log()` instead of `Logger.log()`.  `console.log()` will log information to stackdriver.   `try{ all your function code }catch(e){console.log('Error: ' + e + "\n" + e.stack)}`  From the View menu in the code editor, choose Stackdriver Logging.  For more information, choose Help, Documentation, search troubleshooting.

Comment: @Diego thanks for the tip. My colleagues have free G Suite. They tried different gmail accounts to refresh the report, also they have stopped calling functions for 24 hours. Unfortunately, it didn't helped. Do you know what limits I shoud pay attention to? I've checked triggers running time.

Comment: @AlanWells thanks a lot.  I've tried this method, but the logs didn't appear in Stackdriver. The last issue log was registered in October. Do you know what may be  wrong with logging?

Comment: If you have not created a "standard" GCP project and asssociated the standard GCP project with the Apps Script project, then you won't see any of the logs unless you expand the row in the Executions listing.

Comment: @AlanWells thanks, I followed your instructions and expanded the listing https://nimb.ws/8fijcp Then I opened View in Stackdriver and saw no logs https://nimb.ws/MN0hSf. I also tried to open Apps Script project —> View —> Stackdriver Logging —> and then to find my function by the name https://nimb.ws/8wEVso All I saw were the old error logs https://nimb.ws/CNc2Y5. Would you please give me some clues what I did wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong.  Do a simple test in a new Apps Script file, that does nothing but use `console.log('test')`

Comment: @AlanWells thanks, the test works https://nimb.ws/nTSqPw

Comment: So, maybe the Stackdriver logging issue is a problem isolated to that one Apps Script file?  I don't know.  Anyway.  If you determine the line that is generating the error, you can make a comment and edit your question.

Comment: @AlanWells actually, I've already discovered and described in the question that the problem appears when the Script writes data into the Sheets (setValue). I don't know why it works when I run it, and responses with an error when my colleague tries to do the same, with the same settings.

Comment: You need debugging information from when the editor runs the code to get more information.  If Stackdriver doesn't work when the editor of the spreadsheet runs the code, then log out information to a spreadsheet.  `SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').appendRow(["variable name", variableValue]);`  If the issue is with BigQuery, then it might be a quota issue: [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)

Comment: @AlanWells thank you so much for help! I know that issue is the size of the result table in Google Sheets, because all queries are to small to reach any BQ limits. They are about 100 MB. There are two sheets in the report which are filled with the same method. The first sheet is about 1500 rows, the second — 24000. The issue is with the second sheet. My colleague created a new spreadsheet from her Google account and copied the report there. I can get the result tables in both sheets of that copy, and she can get only the sheet with 1500 rows. So, I believe that the issue is in her G Suite.

Comment: @AlanWells would you please clarify if Google forces any additional restrictions for free accounts (i. e., slowing down the functions or givig less memory resourses) in some cases? May were there two many script invocations from my colleague's IP-address, so that caused additional countermeasures from Google?

Comment: One issue that often happens, is that a service that is called multiple times in rapid succession can hit a short term quota limit.  In order to deal with that, an inner loop with a `try/catch` can be put around that single line, and loop maybe 3 times, and wait on each error.  I have never heard of Google slowing down Apps Script processing for free accounts.  And I have no way of knowing or confirming whether that happens or not.  The quotas and account comparisons are at: [apps-script/guides/services/quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: @AlanWells thanks a lot, I'll try the method with putting  try/catch around single lines.

Answer (score 0):

## Troubleshooting

### Check for file access

Do all your users have access to the data you are trying to retrieve?

### Encapsulate your code with `try` `catch`

If your code is failing due to a Query issue, encapsulate it with `try catch` and `Log` the errors.

### Monitor the execution and determine where it breaks

Use the [Apps Script Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) to determine in which step your code fails and what the variables look like when it does.

### Check [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)

Check the quotas and limits and determine if you have exceeded them. Error messages will point you to this by saying that you were timed out or have to wait before trying again.

#### Script Execution timeout

Apps script also has their own [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), make sure your code can be executed in the time-frame determined.
Specially when dealing with Data In/Out, it's important to use Batch operations.

### If all else fails...

[Contact G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) for your domain.